# linear approximation with respect to L1 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve this problem:
Find the best $L^1$ linear approximation of $e^x$ on [0,1] i.e. minimize 
$\int_0^1|e^x-\alpha-\beta x| dx$

any hints how to proceed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First convince yourself that an optimizer must intersect the graph of $e^x$ exactly twice in the interval $[0,1]$.

Then a better parametrization of the linear approximation is 
$$\ell(x) =  (x - s) \cdot \frac{e^t - e^s}{t-s} + e^s$$
which intersects $e^x$ precisely at $x = s$ and $x = t$.

Then the integral being optimized is

$$ \int_0^s e^x - \ell(x) + \int_s^t \ell(x) - e^x + \int_t^1 e^x - \ell(x) $$
which we compute to be
$$ e^1 - 2 e^t + 2e^s - e^0 + \frac{e^t - e^s}{2(t-s)} ( s^2 + 2(t-s)^2 - (1-s)^2) + e^s(-1 +2t - 2s) $$
The constant parts we don't really care about, the parts depending on $t,s$ we simplify, writing $u = t-s$
$$ 2 e^s( 1 - e^u) + \frac{1}{2u} e^s (e^u - 1)(2s - 1 + 2u^2) + e^s(2u-1) $$

Optimizing we get from taking $\partial_u$
$$ 0 =  - \frac{1}{2u^2} (e^u - 1 - e^u u)(2s -1)  -  (e^u -1 - e^u u) $$
which requires either
$$ 1-2s = 2u^2 \quad \text{or} \quad e^u - 1 - e^u u = 0 $$
The latter is satisfied when $ e^u = 1/(1-u) $ which only holds when $u = 0$ (noting that $u \leq 1$), which we observe corresponds to a local max. So we have $1 - 2s = 2 u^2$

The $\partial_s$ derivative gives
$$ 0 =  \frac{1}{2u}(e^u - 1)(2s + 1 + 2u^2 - 4u) + (2u-1)$$
plugging in from the previous equation we get
$$ 0 = \frac{1}{u}(e^u - 1)(2u - 1) + (2u-1) $$
which only vanishes in $(0,1]$ with $u = \frac12$.

This implies $s = \frac14$.

So, in conclusion, the best linear approximation is
$$ \ell(x) = (x - \frac14) 2 e^\frac14 (e^\frac12 - 1) + e^\frac14 $$

---

One can arrive at this answer slightly more geometrically. Consider $f_+$ the positive part of $e^x - \ell(x)$, and $f_-$ the negative part, where we write 
$$ \ell(x) = \beta (x - \frac12) + \alpha $$
The integral to optimise is $\int f_+ + f_-$.

We see that perturbing $\alpha$ positively decreases $\int f_+$ by exactly the amount $|\mathrm{supp} f_+|$ and increases $\int f_-$ by exactly $|\mathrm{supp} f_-|$. So the degree of freedom in perturbing $\alpha$ requires that the supports of $f_+$ and $f_-$ have the same measure. Since $\ell$ is linear this means the supports must have measure $\frac12$. (Corresponding to $u = \frac12$ above.)

From the convexity of $e^x$ we see that the support of $f_-$ is an interval of length $1/2$. The degree of freedom in $\beta$, which can be interpreted as rotating the line $\ell$ around the point $(\frac12, \alpha)$, can be easily seen to require that the support of $f_-$ is balanced around the point $x  = 1/2$. This leads to the conclusion.

Comment: The numerical values of those coefficients of $\ell$ ($0.42x+1.18$ unless I'm mistaken) does not look right.

Comment: @mickep: thanks, I forgot that 1/(1/2) = 2 and had a typo. The corrected values should be $0.868 + 1.666x$. (The mistake was only in listing the final expression with the numbers plugged in. The derivation was fine.)

Comment: Indeed, nice solution!

Comment: Why must the optimizer intersect the graph of ex exactly twice in the interval?

Comment: @MAS: because if it doesn't, you can always do better. The result proven is interesting enough that I decided to check it again myself, and wrote up a slightly different version on my blog: https://williewong.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/an-optimization-problem-theme/#more-1108 Ruling out zero or one intersection I did by pictures, but it is easy enough to convert that to an $\epsilon, \delta$ statement. (If $e^x > \ell(x) + \delta$, then $\ell(x) + \delta/2$ always does better. The "rotation" case can be treated similarly.)

Comment: Note also that what the answerer didn't state is that the case where $\ell(x)$ is tangent to $e^x$ at one point we count as the situation as having two roots; since the roots are apparently counted with multiplicity in the above write-up (corresponding to $s = t$).