# Identifying a sequence of numbers from an optimization problem in $L^1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, polynomials, systems-of-equations

### Question

Does there exist general closed form solutions (or some sort of recurrence relation) to the system of equations:
$$\begin{align}
x_0 &= -1\\
x_{k+1} &= 1\\
\sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j (x_{j+1} - x_{j}) & = 0 \\
\sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j (x_{j+1}^2 - x_{j}^2) &= 0 \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j (x_{j+1}^k - x_{j}^k) &= 0
\end{align}$$
with $-1 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_k \leq 1$?

For $k$ small the solutions can be computed by hand to be

- $k = 1$: $\{0\}$
- $k = 2$: $\{\pm \frac12\}$
- $k = 3$: $\{0, \pm\frac12\}$
- $k = 4$: $\{(\pm 1\pm\sqrt{5})/4\}$
- $k = 5$: $\{0, \pm\frac12, \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\}$

The non-trivial part of the system can be summarised as
$$  \begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & x_k & x_{k+1} \\
x_0^2 & x_1^2 & x_2^2 & \ldots & x_k^2 & x_{k+1}^2 \\
x_0^3 & x_1^3 & x_2^3 & \ldots & x_k^3 & x_{k+1}^3 \\
& \vdots \\
x_0^k & x_1^k & x_2^k & \ldots & x_k^k & x_{k+1}^k \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
2\\
-2 \\
2 \\
-2 \\
\vdots \\
(-1)^{k-1} 2\\
(-1)^k\end{pmatrix} = 0 $$
if it helps.

### Motivation

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223718/1543) asked for the minimizer among linear functions of the functional $\int_0^1 |e^x - \ell(x)|dx$. The solution given by anonymous user surprised me slightly: it turns out that there is a universal construction that is independent of the target function (in this case, $e^x$). Namely, the user has actually proven that

**Theorem** Let $f\in C^2([-1,1])$ such that $f''$ is strictly signed. Then the minimizer of the functional $\int_{-1}^1 |f(x) - \ell(x)|dx$ among linear functions $\ell(x)$ is attained when 
$$ \ell(x) = (x + 1/2) \left( f(1/2) - f(-1/2)\right) + f(-1/2) $$
in other words, it is the linear interpolation function between $(-1/2, f(-1/2))$ and $(1/2, f(1/2))$.

I gave another write-up of the proof [here on my blog](https://williewong.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/an-optimization-problem-theme/).

It turns out that the theorem extends to the case of "higher order convexity", in the following sense:

**Theorem** There exists a list of numbers $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}\subset [-1,1]$ such that for every $f\in C^k([-1,1])$ such that $f^{(k)}$ is strictly signed, the minimizer of the functional $\int_{-1}^1 |f(x) - p(x)|dx$ among polynomials of degree at most $k-1$ is attained by the $(k-1)$-order polynomial interpolation based on the points $(x_j, f(x_j))$.

I wrote up a proof again on [my blog](https://williewong.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/an-optimization-problem-variation/).

The question above is asking for general closed form expressions of the numbers $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ in terms of $k$.

(If someone happens to know a literature reference for this result, that would also be very nice.)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but your matrix is almost a transposed [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  You can either add a column of 1's and a 0 to the top of your column vector, or factor out the diagonal matrix $(x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_{k+1})$.

Comment: @vadim123: that is not too surprising, since the Vandermonde matrix is closely tied to the Lagrange form of the interpolation polynomials which I made use of in my computations for the second theorem. The main problem is that in usual applications where the vandermonde matrix shows up, one tries to solve the column vector $X$ satisfying $VX = Y$ where $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix and $Y$ is the "target". Here $X$ and $Y$ are given but $V$ is the unknown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your answer for $k=3$ is wrong -- the correct values are $\{0, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \}$.

Second, the answer is $x_{k+1-m} = \cos{\frac{m\pi}{k+1}}, \, m=0\ldots k+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I presume there's an easy proof?

Comment: Expand the cosine as $1/2 (e^{im\theta} + e^{-im\theta})$. Then when you take the $n$th power, you get sums which look like $e^{imn\theta} + e^{-imn\theta}$ plus lower-order terms which cancel due to the relations for $n-2$th, $n-4$th, etc. powers.  These sums are nice geometric sums.

Comment: You should add that into the answer, rather than just in the comments.